# How does .transfer get ether into a testrpc account?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, accounts, contract-debugging

I'm running the CrowdFunding example from the [Solidity docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#structs) and wondering why the ether balance doesn't increase correctly after running `checkGoalReached` in the code below:

```
function checkGoalReached(uint campaignID) returns (bool reached) {
        Campaign storage c = campaigns[campaignID];
        if (c.amount < c.fundingGoal)
            return false;
        uint amount = c.amount;
        c.amount = 0;
        c.beneficiary.transfer(amount);
        return true;
    }
```

Before I run this function, I checked the balance of the 2nd account in my testrpc via `web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[1])` and the result is

```
{ [String: '100000000000000000000'] s: 1, e: 20, c: [ 1000000 ] }
```

After running `checkGoalReached` a transaction posts in testrpc but after running `getBalance` again, this is the result:

```
{ [String: '100000000000000016000'] s: 1, e: 20, c: [ 1000000, 16000 ] }
```

Why doesn't the original 1,000,000 ether increase to 1,016,000 but rather creates a 2nd element in the balance?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it from BigNumber. Web3 includes this automatically.

```
resultOfgetBalance.toNumber();
```

And you'll have your correct amount. BigNumber is stored as an array to compute exceptionally large numbers.

Comment: By running `web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[1]).toNumber()` in the console, I get 100000000000000020000' as the result. I was expecting 1,016,000, still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: You're getting the amount in wei, not Ether. it is 18 decimals delineated. Pass the result to `web3.fromWei(result, 'ether');` and it will fix the many zeros issue for you.

As for the 20000 vs 16000 result, well, I would assume you have the wrong amount being transferred.

It would do you some benefit to dig a little deeper in Solidty documentation regarding decimalization and how values of Ether/tokens are stored.